# SendKeys "^f" does not work with another shortcut key

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

I have a form with a webbrowser control and a Button (Find Button)
Below is the code for find button. Web browser control contains some text and when Find button is clicked the Find dialog opens. we use SendKeys "^f" to open the find dialog.

But find dialog does not open when I use the shortcut key of Find button(Alt+N).

Can someone please help on this?

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  WebBrowser1.SetFocus
  WebBrowser1.Refresh2
  SendKeys "^f"

  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's happening, but I suspect the key press is interfering with the SendKeys. Instead of worrying about how to make that work use the ExecWB method instead.

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    WebBrowser1.SetFocus
    WebBrowser1.ExecWB OLECMDID_FIND, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```